# Accessing dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi in my code there is a dictionary of dictionary.

```
nrec={'bridge': 'xapi1', 'current_operations': {}, 'uuid': '9ae5ca7d-e7d6-7a81-f619-d0ea33efb534', 'tags': [], 'other_config': {'is_guest_installer_network': 'true', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'ip_end': '192.168.128.254', 'ip_begin': '192.168.128.1'}, 'name_label': 'Guest installer network', 'VIFs': ['OpaqueRef:dff106aa-1a94-8384-1c86-862b47c87fcf'], 'allowed_operations': [], 'PIFs': [], 'name_description': 'Network on which guests will get assigned a private local IP address', 'MTU': '1500', 'blobs': {}}
```

Here you can see inside this dictionary one more dictionary `'other_config': {'is_guest_installer_network': 'true', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'ip_end': '192.168.128.254', 'ip_begin': '192.168.128.1'}` is there.

I want to check `is_guest_installer_network=="true"`

I have done `nrec["other_config"]["is_guest_installer_network"]== "true"` but the problem is some attribute have this other_config property with either empty value or different value. Then in this case my solution will throw exception. So i want to do it in a efficient way like If is_guest_installer_network is consists in the dictionary and the value (string) is true or not.

Comment: what do you want to return if the value is not present: `False` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a config item, you shouldn't need to access it very often (thus your efficiency requirement would be questionable). Configure once and forget about it (e.g. set `self.is_guest_installer_network = True`).

If you can't forget about it, it would depend on the likelihood of the entry being present in your dictionary. If it's more likely that the item is missing it would probably be better if you do something like the following. You get some shortcut behavior if an item misses, the other config dict is looked up only once (for the existance check and for the value following lookup.

```
def check_guest_installer_network(nrec):
  other_config = nrec.get("other_config", None)
  return other_config is not None and other_config.get('is_guest_installer_network', False)
```

If it's more likely that the item is there, the lazy try/except approach could be better suited. As the saved check performance, would outweigh the additional performance cost when the exception actually needs to be handled.

```
def check_guest_installer_network(nrec):
  try:
    return nrec["other_config"]['is_guest_installer_network'] == "true"
  except KeyError:
    return False
```

After all, if this check indeed has a significant impact on the overall performance, you should put this variable somewhere it is better accessible, than in a nested dictionary, e.g. put it into a global/class member variable once, and enjoy the cheap and easy checks afterwards.

You should have a look at the [cprofile module](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) to verify that this lookup is indeed the bottleneck of your software, that is worth the optimization effort. And You should look at the [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#examples) to choose the most performant solution for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
nrec["other_config"].get('is_guest_installer_network')
```

It'll return its value if `'is_guest_installer_network'` exists in `nrec['other_config']`

Comment: Worth to mention that if key is not present then `get` will return `None`. Anyway, +1 for this. I forgot about `get` while writing my own answer(now deleted).

Answer (score 0):

Just check

```
'other_config' in nrec and 'is_guest_installer_network' in nrec['other_config'] and nrec['other_config']['is_guest_installer_network'] == 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a key exists in a dictionary use:

```
if 'key' in dictionary:
    # do sth
```

So your code will be:

```
if 'other_config' in nrec and 'is_guest_installer_network' in nrec['other_config'] and nrec['other_config']['is_guest_installer_network'] == 'true':
    # do sth
```

Additionally if you want default value if the key is not present in the dict use `get(key, default)` method:

```
nrec.get('other_config', default_value_here)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is

```
>>> try:
    if nrec["other_config1"]["is_guest_installer_network"] == 'true':
        print 'Do Something'
except (KeyError,TypeError):
    None #Or do something logical
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to avoid exception is either `try .. except`,  or use `dictionary` built-in methods.

```
my_dict = {'one': {'two': 'hello world!'}, 'four': 'Dummy!'}
try:
  my_name = my_dict['one']['two']
except:
  pass
  // instead of pass, you can also return something or do something else

try:
  my_dict['one']['two']
except Exception as e:
  my_name = 'default'
  return my_name, e  // returns a tuple which contains 'default' and error message


#or use has_key()

# this is for one-level nested dictionary
for id, items in my_dict.iteritems():
     if items.has_key('two'):
          //do something

# or simply this  --> eliminates dummy for loop
if my_dict['one'].has_key('two'):      // has_key returns True / False
      // do something

# or use in operator  (replace has_key)
if 'two' in my_dict['one'].keys():
     // do something


# or get method

my_dict['one'].get('two', 'Default')
```

Get is nice if that's all you need to avoid exception.

Answer (score -1):

You've got the answer

```
nrec["other_config"]["is_guest_installer_network"]== "true"
```

can be written like

```
if nrec.has_key("other_config") and type(nrec["other_config"]) == type({}) and nrec["other_config"].has_key("....") and nrec["other_config"]["is_guest_installer_network"]== "true":
```

But this is sort of ugly.

Or, as noted in the comments

```
nrec.get("other_config",{}).get("is_guest_installer_network",{}) == "true"
```

But this doesn't handle the type checking.

Maybe best to do something like this

```
def traverse(_dict, keys):
    val = _dict
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        if key in val and type(val[key]) is dict :
            val = val[key]
        else:
            return None
    return val.get(keys[-1],None)
```

Comment: -1: This can be done much better done by using the native method `.get()` on dictionaries, which has a configurable default value as second argument.